# how to round up a digit after a decimal

Tags: c#

i want to round up a number after the decimal point to 2 numbers in c#.

ex: input: 100.175
    ouput: 100.17

```
input:100.176
output:100.18 (as the number after two digits is above 5,rounding up to 6)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you looked at `Math.Round`? (You probably want the `decimal` type rather than `double` though.)

Comment: There is an overload to Math.Round where you can specify how to handle MidpointRounding.  

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ef48waz8(v=vs.110).aspx for the overload and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.midpointrounding(v=vs.110).aspx for the midpoint part.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
decimal num = 100.176M;
string strNum = num.ToString("N2");
```

[Demonstration](https://ideone.com/azFoHi)

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you need:

```
result = Math.Round(MyNum, 2);
```

Although it should be clear, the 1st argument is the number to round, and the 2nd argument is the number of decimal places you want.